# How could I use ic command in bash?

Tags: bash

My console is not able to recognize ic command in a bash script.

I need to run this command to do some calculation but I get this message `ic: command not found`.

How could I define it in the bash?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?

Comment: It would help if we knew what that command was, or where it comes from.

Comment: Talking about calculations, maybe you're referring to `bc` or `dc`?

Comment: `ic` is a calculator similar to `bc` but with more capability. It was renamed some time ago but I can't find the new name at the moment. You'll have to install the new package and either change your script to use the new name or link the new name to `ic`. I'll see if I can find the new name.

Comment: Eureka! It's now called `nickle` and you can find it at `nickle.org`.

Answer (score 3):

The error message that you are getting indicates that the command `ic` is not present in any of the directories contained in the `PATH` environment variable.

To find the directories that bash searches for executable files type the following at the command line

```
echo $PATH
```

If you know where the `ic` command is on your file system then you could specify the full path to ic in your bash script so that it does not have to use the PATH environment variable to find it.

So lets say that ic was in the directory `/usr/local/bin` then in your bash script you could execute ic by entering.

```
/usr/local/bin/ic
```

rather than

```
ic
```

Comment: (or OP could add add `PATH=:$PATH:/usr/local/bin` someplace in their environment.) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

The message `ic: command not found.` indicated that the command ic was not found. In other words, it is not in one of the places where your shell looks for the command.

Usually this is because the command is in the current directory, which (unlike in the default in windows) is not in the default search path.

If this is the case then you can either start it with supplying the full path or by adding the path it is in to the search path.

Examples:

- `/usr/local/bin/ic` to start a program called ic in the folder /usr/local/bin/
- `/opt/bin/ic` to start a program called ic in the folder /opt/bin/
- `./ic` to start a program called ic in the current directory.
  Note this is not in the path by default. If you add it to a path, make it the last entry. E.g use `PATH=:$PATH:.` and **not** `PATH=.:$PATH`. ($PATH is the old path, the colomn is a separator, the dot is the current directory).

If ic is a script then you can also start it by invoking its interpreter.

For example if ic is a bash script then you can use `/usr/local/bin/bash ic`

If ic is a script and the current directory is already in you path then check these three things:

1. The program (ic) has its e**x**ecute bit set. (If that is not the case then `chmod  +x ic`).
2. The script has a shebang specifying a proper interpreter.
   A shebang is the `#!` at the very first line in the script. It must be the first line. No empty lines above it. For a bash script the proper entry is `#!/usr/local/bin/env bash`. (`#!/usr/local/bin/bash` will also work if your bash is in /usr/local/bin, but if you move to another system where it is installed in a different place then you will need to edit that file. The env program (which is always installed in the same place) solves that issue.)
3. If it is a script and there is a shebang, make sure that it has a proper line ending. This is something which often goes wrong when a script is edited on Windows which uses a different line ending than unices. (^J^M on windows, ^J on unix, and ^M on a Mac). The result is that env might be looking for a program called `bash^M`, and this might not be obvious when a helpful (as in *clippy style helpful* editor decides to *help* you by not showing the ^M's).

Answer (score 2):

`ic` is now called `nickle`, as explained [here](http://nickle.org/name.html). You can obtain it from [nickle.org](http://nickle.org/), but it would be better if you could use your distribution's package manager as I think it has some dependencies. For example, on an Ubuntu system, you can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install nickle
```

Then you can either change your script to use `nickle` instead of `ic`, or you can link `nickle` to `ic`, e.g.,

```
ln -s /usr/bin/nickle ~/bin/ic
```